# how to init customtkinter window and toplevel on the center of the screen

Tags: python, customtkinter

there is a way to init the window or toplevel in the center of the screen? no matter the scale? using eval method and (width//2, height//2) does not work. I don't found a similar question using customtkinter on google.

Im trying to init my app on the center of the screen but it does offset to the right, using eval("tk::...etc") method does not work, and using winfo.widthscreen//2...etc offset even further. And for toplevel get the same problem, im using 150% scale on Windows, res 2560x1600. But it has to work on every resolution or scale.

Comment: Welcome to [so], please consider taking the [tour] and visiting the [help]. There you find helpful links like [ask] and [mre]. Good luck with your question.